# VBA code for changing fillcolor of shape based on value in cell

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("E9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        If Target.Value < 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In cell E9 I have the formula:

```
=IF(H9="";"";INDEX(Sales!E39:P39;MATCH(Main!AE3;Sales!E34:P34;0)))
```

This doesn't seem to work, only if I write manually for example 500 in E9.
Any solutions?

Comment: Does your Index/Match formula return a value when you don't enter one manually?

Comment: Index/match formula return values when I change the month in a drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sheet Change Event doesn't get triggered when the cell content is changed by a formula. To achieve this you need Sheet Calculate Event rather.

Give this a try. Place the following code on Sheet Module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = Range("E9")
If IsNumeric(cell) Then
    If cell.Value < 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @TheNarsisisst You're welcome! Glad it worked for you. Please take a minute to accept the answer as Solution to mark your question as Solved. :)

Comment: @TheNarsisisst you are free to accept the answer, if it helps you, this means a lot to people.

Comment: @sktneer beat me to it :D